# Actual Enum validator

Tags: laravel

The current enum validator expects a scalar value:

```
'status' => [new Enum(ServerStatus::class)]
```

In my case, I'm converting the scalar value to an actual enum via:

```
 prepareForValidation()
```

Once the scalar value is converted into an actual enum, how can I validate it? Something like this:

```
'status' => 'enum:App\Enums\Status'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use(new EnumValue) or (new EnumKey )instead of (new Enum)
and it will be 'status' => [new EnumValue(ServerStatus::class)]
as it is in the [doc]: https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum/blob/master/README.md#validation

Comment: Sorry but why are you pointing to an external library? I'd like to use a native Laravel solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don´think you understand validation. the Enum expects the classname and it uses the string value passed into the validator to check if it can make an enum of that type with it. if you already turned it successfully into an enum, it's already validated.